# Executing PL/SQL code after new increment

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a pl/sql code to send emails(which is working fine). However I will like for it to be executed when a new entry is made in the user table and disregard the old entries.

> scenario. new user is entered (pl/sql code executes). If I open the
>   table and no new user is entered(no execution of pl/sql code).
>
> if 2 weeks later a new user is entered (code executes)

so code only executes when a new entry is in the table

Below is the trigger to create a new ID when a new user is entered

```
create or replace trigger "BI_TEST"   
  before insert on "TEST"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."ID" is null then 
    select "TEST_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID" from sys.dual; 
  end if; 
end;
```

below is the code for sending emails

```
BEGIN
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => 'user@gmail.com',
                recipients => 'user1@gmail.com',

                subject    => 'UTL_MAIL Test',
                message    => 'If you get this message it worked!');
END;
/
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: let me edit my above question

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a trigger to send an email when a new row is inserted into a table. I would leave your existing trigger alone, and add an after-insert trigger. Imagine if you inserted a new user, but the data violated a constraint - the insert would get rolled back, but a before-insert trigger would still send a notification email.

```
create or replace trigger "AI_TEST_EMAIL"   
  after insert on "TEST"               
  for each row  
begin   
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => 'user@gmail.com',
                recipients => 'user1@gmail.com',
                subject    => 'New user created',
                message    => 'A new row was inserted in TEST with username: ' || :NEW.username );
end;
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to mark this question as answered if @kfinity's response resolved the issue you were having. Thanks.